# How to wait for the response from the Other server in java

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, integration

I am about to communicating with other server to get the required data in my Java-Gwt web application. I need to execute some functionality based on the response from that server. The following is the flow of communication between 2 parties.
1) I am sending request to other server from my servlet with required input parameters.
2) Based on the request i sent, other server will give the response.
3) Before sending the response other server will do some heavy processing.So it may take some time.
4) But at my side i should wait for the response from that sever otherwise i can not go further

Question: 
 a) How to wait for the response from the other server? some times it will give HTTP Error if it takes more time to get response.

Comment: Sounds like you need to spend some time to learn JMS

Comment: @gerrytan, I do not know JMS, May i know, is that only way to solve my problem?

Comment: are you using with GWT RPC ? what's wrong with async callback ?

Comment: Not, of course. But it good solution. I was surprised, that gwt client can reseive JMS message. Thanks to @gerrytan! I suppose, any others solutions will implement JMS paradigm by other ways.

Comment: No the communication happens b/n two servers.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion, the best way is to assure your UI is not blocked waiting for response. One of the most popular solutions consists in delegate the request to a `Message-Driven Bean` to avoid blocking the UI. Then the UI is available to do other things. Once the `message bean` has processed the request, it can send a callback. The way of implementing that callback depends on how you like most. Many times, that callback is not send to a another bean, but is send to the user - or group of users attached to this kind of request - instead.